# Following the Laravel basic login: please explain a listener

Tags: authentication, laravel, frameworks, listener

I was trying to follow basic auth for laravel and get how it generally works but am stuck in one area:

- call basic login: https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/Guard.php#L283
- attempt basic login: https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/Guard.php#L316
- attempt to login users with given credentials:
  https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/Guard.php#L355
- fire attempt: 
  https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/Guard.php#L394
- the $this->events variable is a object that follows the dispatcher interface. Here's the fire method signature + description:
  https://github.com/illuminate/contracts/blob/master/Events/Dispatcher.php#L40

My question is with the last part: "Fire an event and call the listeners"

So I get that the event is authentication. What listeners are you calling in this context / what are they / what do they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a good example on documentation of Laravel 4.2: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events (see section Basic Usage -> Subscribing To An Event). In this case you can do something after user do the auth. As you see in an example it's a smart way to update last login date.

Comment: oh cool! thanks

Aside from updating the last login date, what typical things do you see done post login in regards to updating other relevant objects? (ex maybe session or other user attributes)

Comment: It depends on the project, what you actual goals are. It may be that you won't need listener here at all.